# convex hull of a lower hemicontinuous correspondence is lower hemicontinuous

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis, set-valued-analysis

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}')$ be two topological spaces.

We call a correspondence (set-valued function) $F: X \rightarrow 2^Y$ lower semicontinuous if for every $G \in \mathcal{T}'$ , $\{x \in X\mid F(x) \cap  G \neq \phi\} \in \mathcal{T}$ holds.

> Consider a lower semi-continuous correspondence $F: X \rightarrow 2^Y:
>  x \mapsto F(x)$. Show that $c(F): X \rightarrow 2^Y: x \mapsto c(F(x))$ , where $c(A)$ denotes the convex hull of $A$ in $Y$, is also lower
>   semi-continuous.

This is a claim I came across in C.D. Aliprantis and K.C. Border's "Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide". It is also a proposition in Ernest Michael's first paper on Continuous selections. However, I'm failing to prove this by just using the definitions I know.

Comment: What is the convex hull of $F$? $x \mapsto \operatorname{conv}(F(x))$?

Comment: @gerw Indeed, this is wat I meant. The edit should make it more clear now.

Comment: What sort of space is $Y$ supposed to be, to be speaking of convex subsets?  Also, why does the title mention "hemicontinuous"?

Answer (score 0):

We will consider *partial case* : Assume that $X,\ Y$ are isometric to
$\mathbb{R}^2$.

For a fixed $G\in \mathcal{T}'$ define $B=
\bigg\{ x\in X \bigg| c(F(x))\bigcap G \neq \emptyset \bigg\}$

Let $g\in c(F(x)) \bigcap G\neq \emptyset$ Hence $x\in B$ **We will show that there is open set $T$ with $x\in T$ and $T\subset B$** :

Hence $g =\sum_{i=1}^3\ c_iy_i $ is a *convex combination* of $y_i,\
1\leq i\leq 3$ in $F(x)$. And assume that open ball $B(g,r)$ is in
$G$.

Consider open balls $B(y_i,r_i)$ Define $$ T =\bigcap_{i=1}^3\ \bigg\{
a\bigg|F(a)\bigcap B(y_i,r_i)\neq \emptyset\bigg\}$$ Here $T$ is intersection of three open sets, since $F$ is semi-continuous And $x\in T$ so that $T$
is nonempty open set.

Assume that $ \sum_{i=1}^3\ c_i B(y_i,r_i)$ is in $B(g,r)$ for sufficiently small $r_i$. Hence $B$ contains an open set $T$